# Domain transfer to a provider that doesn't support .DK?

Tags: domain, tld

Is it possible to transfer a country code domain from one domain provider to another and that one transferred to does not sell that country code domain (in this case .DK)?

Answer (score 2):

Typically not, but you'd be better asking them rather than us - because they'll know you see.

Answer (score 1):

As I told you in the other question, this is absolutely not possible. Registrars do a whole lot more for you than simply take your money.

Comment: That's not correct. Some registrars are able to accept transfers for domains they cannot sell directly.

Comment: True. He was asking earlier about domains that registrars did not support at all.

Answer (score 0):

In the case of .dk domains it is impossible as [DK-Hostmaster](https://www.dk-hostmaster.dk/) controls and manages them all.

You can purchase a .dk domain from a normal registrar but from the 2nd year onward you are billed directly by DK-Hostmaster.